# Setting radio group from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, getjson

I have 2 radio groups in a modal form..  I am having a difficult time figuring out how to set the value for each group from a json string..  The last 2 values in the json string is "role" and "activated".  Activate is either 1 for Yes or 0 for now.  Role is either 1, 2 or 3 for Admin, Staff or User.  I loop thru the json string and assign the values to field names since they are all identical in the html.

My html is:

```
<div class="form-field bt-space10">
    <div class="clear">
    <h4 class="fl-space2 ln-22 size-120" style="color:#777777; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;">Authorization Role: </h4>
                                
    <div class="form-radio-item clear fl-space2">
        <input type="radio" rel="radiogroup" name="role" id="Admin" value="1" class="radio fl-space" /> <label for="Admin" class="fl">Admin</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-radio-item clear fl-space2">
        <input type="radio" rel="radiogroup" name="role" id="Staff" value="2" class="radio fl-space" /> <label for="Staff" class="fl">Staff</label>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="form-radio-item clear fl-space2">
        <input type="radio" rel="radiogroup" name="role" id="User" value="3" class="radio fl-space" /> <label for="User" class="fl">User</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    <h4 class="fl-space2 ln-22 size-120" style="color:#777777; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;">Account Activated: </h4>
                                
    <div class="form-radio-item clear fl-space2">
        <input type="radio" rel="radiogroup1" name="activated" id="Yes" class="radio fl-space" /> <label for="radio4" class="fl">Yes</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-radio-item clear fl-space2">
        <input type="radio" rel="radiogroup1" name="activated" id="No" class="radio fl-space" /> <label for="radio5" class="fl">No</label>
    </div>  
    </div>  
        
</div><!-- /.form-field-->
```

My incoming json string (if needed, I could change the return to "Role":"Admin", etc.. and "activated":"Yes", etc.):

```
{"op": "UPDATE", "id": "7","email": "joe@public.com","name": "Joe Public","address": "123 Any Street","city": "AnyTown","zipcode": "12345","state": "PA","contact_name": "","phone": "8885551212","fax": "","company_branch": "","company_name": "","activated": "1","role": "1" }
```

The code I use to populate other fields on the form:

```
function editUser(rowID, callback) {
    var ret;
    jQuery.fancybox({
        modal : true,
        padding : 0,
        cache : false,
        overlayOpacity : 0.5,
        href : "userEdit.html",
        onComplete : function() {
            InitProfileMenu()
            var tsTimeStamp= new Date().getTime();
            $.getJSON("includes/GetUserDetails.php?tsTimeStamp&id=" + rowID,     
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    $('#' + i).val(item);
                });
            })
            jQuery("#editUser_cancel").click(function() {
                ret = false;
                jQuery.fancybox.close();
            })
            jQuery("#editUser_ok").click(function() {
                jQuery.fancybox.close();
                ret = true;
            })
        },
```

I have Googled this to death and not finding a solution.  Anyone have any ideas? or a resource they can point me to which would help figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to resolve in a generic way for all values in your JSON string because the html attribues are not like one another. I suggest two changes:

1. Add a value attribute to the radio inputs named "activated"
2. For each element of JSON data: check the type of form input, if radio, use name and value attribute selectors to check the correct one.

   ```
    var myJsonData = {
       "op": "UPDATE",
        "id": "7",
       "email": "joe@public.com",
       "name": "Dennis Megarry",
       "address": "123 Any Street",
       "city": "AnyTown",
       "zipcode": "12345",
       "state": "PA",
       "contact_name": "",
       "phone": "8885551212",
       "fax": "",
       "company_branch": "",
       "company_name": "",
       "activated": "1",
       "role": "1"
   };

   function updateFormWithJson(dataObj) {
       $.each(dataObj,function(i,item){
           if($('input[name="' + i + '"]:first').attr("type") == "radio"){
               $('input[name="' + i + '"][value="' + item + '"]').attr("checked","checked");
           }
       });
   };

   $(document).ready(function() {
       updateFormWithJson(myJsonData);
   });

   <div class="form-field bt-space10">
       <div class="clear">
       <h4 class="fl-space2 ln-22 size-120" style="color:#777777; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;">Authorization Role: </h4>

       <div class="form-radio-item clear fl-space2">
           <input type="radio" rel="radiogroup" name="role" id="Admin" value="1" class="radio fl-space" /> <label for="Admin" class="fl">Admin</label>
       </div>

       <div class="form-radio-item clear fl-space2">
           <input type="radio" rel="radiogroup" name="role" id="Staff" value="2" class="radio fl-space" /> <label for="Staff" class="fl">Staff</label>
       </div>  

       <div class="form-radio-item clear fl-space2">
           <input type="radio" rel="radiogroup" name="role" id="User" value="3" class="radio fl-space" /> <label for="User" class="fl">User</label>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div class="clear">
       <h4 class="fl-space2 ln-22 size-120" style="color:#777777; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;">Account Activated: </h4>

       <div class="form-radio-item clear fl-space2">
           <input type="radio" rel="radiogroup1" name="activated" id="Yes" value="1" class="radio fl-space" /> <label for="radio4" class="fl">Yes</label>
       </div>

       <div class="form-radio-item clear fl-space2">
           <input type="radio" rel="radiogroup1" name="activated" id="No" value="0" class="radio fl-space" /> <label for="radio5" class="fl">No</label>
       </div>  
   </div>
   ```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I was trying to do it in the same function but looks like I was off in the wrong direction.. again.. lol  Thanks!